# Call to FakeItEasy mocked mediatr.send method fails assertion

Tags: unit-testing, controller, xunit, mediatr, fakeiteasy

I am new to FakeItEasy and I am having a problem asserting if an async method has been called. It fails assertion because it hasn't been called. I have done my best to ensure the assertion matches the configured call but still no dice.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(CreateOwnerRequest requestModel)
        {
            var command = new CreateOwnerCommand { RequestModel = requestModel };
            var ownerResponse = await _mediator.Send(command, default);
                       
            //TODO: return URI for the new resources
            return Created("", ownerResponse);
        }
```

```
        [Theory]
        [ClassData(typeof(ValidCreateOwnerTestData))]
        public async void ShouldCallCreateOwnerHandler(CreateOwnerRequest validCreateOwnerModel)
        {
            // Arrange
            var fakeMediator = A.Fake<IMediator>();
            A.CallTo(() => fakeMediator.Send(new CreateOwnerCommand { RequestModel = validCreateOwnerModel },
                default)).Returns(A.Dummy<Task<OwnerResponse>>());
            var ownerController = new OwnerController(fakeMediator);

            // Act
            _ = await ownerController.Post(validCreateOwnerModel);

            // Assert
            A.CallTo(() => fakeMediator.Send(new CreateOwnerCommand { RequestModel = validCreateOwnerModel },
                default)).MustHaveHappened();
        }
```

```
    public class ValidCreateOwnerTestData : IEnumerable<object[]>
    {
        public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return new object[] { new CreateOwnerRequest { FirstName = "Foo", LastName = "Bar" } };
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your assertion, you create a new instance of `CreateOwnerRequest`. Obviously, this isn't the same instance that is actually used in the controller action, so it isn't considered equal, and the assertion fail.

You *could* override `Equals` on `CreateOwnerRequest` so that they are considered equal, but it's probably not a good idea, since you would do it only in order to satisfy the assertion.

A better approach is to use [argument constraints](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/argument-constraints/) to specify a condition that the argument must match:

```cs
// Assert
A.CallTo(() => fakeMediator.Send(
    A<CreateOwnerCommand>.That.Matches(command => /* some condition here */))
    A<CancellationToken>.Ignored))
    .MustHaveHappened();
```

(note that I also changed `default` to `A<CancellationToken>.Ignored`, because you probably don't want the assertion to fail if the controller action starts using a real cancellation token...)

Comment: That did it. I really appreciate the help. I know understand a little better how the matching works.